# Java IO exception when running "kill -s SIGINT ${pid}"

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm running a jibri instance with some modifications from the official repo. When I quit recording, the recordings are saved, but the video doesnt play (EOF issue).

On debugging, found that "kill -s SIGINT ${pid}" command is invoked to kill the running ffmped process.

This results in the below error:

```
Jibri 2023-07-31 06:06:24.033 SEVERE: [47] [session_id=olvwnkybhwjarcfs] ProcessWrapper.stopAndWaitFor#117: Error stopping process
jitsi-meet-jibri-1  | java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "kill -9 821": error=2, No such file or directory
jitsi-meet-jibri-1  |   at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
jitsi-meet-jibri-1  |   at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
```

This whole process runs inside a docker container. When I sh into the docker container and manually kill ffmpeg, the recording is saved and is playable.

The server has enough resources, so no problems there.

This is the piece of code that triggers the kill command:

```
 val cmdArr = arrayOf<String>("kill -s SIGINT ${process.pidValue}")
        runtime.exec(cmdArr, null)
```

I'm not that familiar with java/kotlin, so not sure what is happening here.

Using Openjdk 11

Any insights will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass all arguments as separate elements of the array:

```
val cmdArr = arrayOf<String>("kill", "-s", "SIGINT", process.pidValue.toString())
```